# MailCore2 Is it possible to check which email email has been replied iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mailcore2

I am working on an iphone app which uses MailCore2 to fetch and send emails. Everything is working fine. I want to set a flag which will display that an email has been replied. Is it possible with MailCore2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a convention for email app to set a replied flag on the message that has just been replied. That said, that convention might not be followed very properly, especially, more recently.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the MailCore2 Documentation I have found that we have to include the MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags in the MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind as in the following example:

```
  MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind =
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFullHeaders|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindExtraHeaders|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindGmailThreadID|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindGmailMessageID|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindGmailLabels|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindInternalDate|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindStructure|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindUid|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindExtraHeaders|
    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders;
```

Then we have to check for

```
    MCOMessageFlagAnswered
```

like this in the MCOIMAPMessage (m) object

```
    if (m.flags & MCOMessageFlagAnswered) {
        //replied
    }else{
        //not replied 
    }
```